# jQuery event listener give me the same value when the I click different link

Tags: jquery, selector

I made a jsfiddle of the problem

http://jsfiddle.net/XXVAP/

the problem is whatever item I click it keeps showing me the last id(which is  10)

This's driving me crazy! Help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because you are alerting a predefined variable. In your for loop you are updating the value of the `id` variable, in last iteration it's value become `10` and you are alerting this variable in each element's click handler. You should use `this.id`:

```
alert(this.id);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2dfkh/

Note that event in your code is `undefined`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I still confused but it works, I'll figure it out later

Answer (score 1):

The problem can be reduced to this...

```
var l = 10;
for(var i = 0; i < l; ++i) {
    $("#item-" + i).click(function() {
        alert(i);
    });
}
```

The contents of the click function are not evaluated at the time it goes through the loop instead when you click on the element it will run that function and alert whatever `i` is at the time... In this case it will be 10. To keep hold of the value it is at the time you can do a number of things.

Pass the value to the element as a data item.

```
var l = 10;
for(var i = 0; i < l; ++i) {
    $("#item-" + i).data("id", i).click(function() {
        alert($(this).data("id"));
    });
}
```

Create an inner enclosure, it looks tricky but all it is is a function that is being called immediately that returns the click handler function.

```
var l = 10;
for(var i = 0; i < l; ++i) {
    $("#item-" + i).click((function(n) {
        return function() {
            alert(n);
        }
    })(i));
}
```

You could also write it...

```
function handler(n) {
    return function() {
        alert(n);
    }
}
var l = 10;
for(var i = 0; i < l; ++i) {
    $("#item-" + i).click(handler(i));
}
```

Or you could do the entire bind as a new function...

```
function bindElement(n) {
    $("#item-" + n).click(function() {
        alert(n);
    });
}
var l = 10;
for(var i = 0; i < l; ++i) {
    bindElement(i);
}
```

---

**Note:** W3C specificiations state that an id should not start with a number, http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/types.html#type-name 6.2, bullet 2. to make the HTML valid you should prepend it with a string.

---

Here is a fiddle showing the different solutions http://jsfiddle.net/XXVAP/8/

Comment: +1 for your example code and explanation, it's 3:00 AM in New Zealand, I'll look at your answer in detail tomorrow, thanks a lot